# Find differently styled date in comments

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a another question for `preg_match`.

I have a table, where the date of the comment is written inside the comment itself ( by hand ) and now I need to extract that date and place in a different column.

I found out, that the comments and dates are styled like this:

```
+-------+----------------------+--------------+
| id    | warning_sent         | warning_date |
+-------+----------------------+--------------+
|  6109 | 2011-06-28           | 0000-00-00   |
|  6123 | 2012 02 14           | 0000-00-00   |
|  6126 | Some text 18.11.10\n | 0000-00-00   | /* This is 2010-11-18 */
| 13750 | 2011-06-28\n         | 0000-00-00   |
|  8108 | 7-01-2010            | 0000-00-00   |
|  9954 | 2012.07.03           | 0000-00-00   |
|  6110 | Some text 21-02-2011 | 0000-00-00   |
+-------+----------------------+--------------+
```

Now, the only thing, I could think of ( and *know* how to do ), is looking for the first number, then for the last. And somehow analyzing the string in between, but this comes to a serious problem if the comment text contains a number on its own.

So the question is: **How can I find all the dates ( there are only one in each comment ) inside the comments and store them automatically inside the other column in my desired YYYY-MM-DD format?**

*Edit:* This worked, thanx [@infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464552/infinity)

```
$query = "SELECT id, warning_sent FROM data";
$result = qq( $query );

foreach( $result as $values )
{
    preg_match( '/[\d]{4}((-|\s|\.)[\d]{2}){2}|([\d]{1,2}(\.|-)){2}[\d]{2,4}/', $values['warning_sent'], $matches );

    $old_date = $matches[0];
    $new_date = '0000-00-00';

    /* 2011-06-28, 2012 02 14, 18.11.10, 7-01-2010, 2012.07.03, 21-02-2011, 20.10.2010 */
    $formattings = array( 'Y-m-d', 'Y m d', 'd.m.Y', 'd.m.y', 'j-m-Y', 'Y.m.d', 'd-m-Y' );

    for( $k=0; $k<sizeof( $formattings ); $k++ )
    {
        $sub_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( $formattings[$k], $old_date );
        $sub_date = (array)$sub_date;
        $timestamp = strtotime( $sub_date['date'] );
        $check_date = date( $formattings[$k], $timestamp );
        if( $old_date == $check_date ) $new_date = date( 'Y-m-d', $timestamp );
    }

    $warning_sent_date[$values['id']] = $new_date;

}
```

Comment: Does it follow some specific format/s

Comment: @infinity As you can see, there are 3 different formats of the dates used.

Comment: @DainisAbols do the dates have a exact position? (i.e. at the end, at the begining ect.?)

Comment: @Sidath As you can see, **no**. The comments are written by hand. It varies how/where the operator decided to enter the date in the comment.

Comment: @DainisAbols Just a suggestion. you can always add a seperate input field to get date from the user input. quicker. better. easier

Comment: @Sidath This is a fairly old db and as you can see from my example, I intend to put all the dates in the new column in the future. I just need this, for the old entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just these 3 formats that should work

```
'/[\d]{4}((-|\s|\.)[\d]{2}){2}|([\d]{1,2}(\.|-)){2}[\d]{2,4}/'
```

**Updates RegEx**

http://regexr.com?32pbf

Comment: works just fine. I update the question with my final code, if interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match` to *find* rows with dates embedded in the comments. Others have presented ways of doing that.

However, MySQL has no built in function to perform regular-expression substitution. For example, the Oracle dbms offers REGEXP_REPLACE (see here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) but MySQL does no.

So you are going to have to use client code to retrieve each row with a date in the comment field, extract the date, and update the row.  It's a nuisance, eh?

Comment: There is no problem going over the results in PHP. That's what I'm doing anyways.